# Accessing a database on the Mysql server with the same user, is there a performance problem?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server with many databases, access each database with a specific user or access each database using a single user, is there any difference in performance.

Can I create a single user to access all databases? Are there any performance issues?

Answer (score 4):

"Tables" are important for "performance"; databases and users are not.

A `DATABASE` is merely a way to organize multiple tables.  Essentially no performance impact, just convenience for `JOINing` and assigning permissions: `GRANT ... ON dbname.* ...`, for example.

A "user" (again, showing up in `GRANT`) is mostly a convenience in assigning permissions and, hence, security.  Most of the "user" work is done during "connecting".  During a query, there is [perhaps] the same amount of effort to check permissions regardless of how the users are structured.

"Roles" are a handy way to assign the same permissions to a get of users.

As the first cut for "security", assign one or more users to each project and then `GRANT ... ON dbname.* ... TO user@...`.  Reserve `GRANT ... ON *.*` *only* to `root` (`admin`) and certain 'system' functions, such as replication.  Also, have code users (such as a UI) run as one "user" and assign each user their own "user" name (and limited permissions).

Any number of users can be granted access to the same database(s) (or table(s)).  When two users (human and/or UI) are touching the same row of the same table of the same database, special code is invoked to prevent them from messing up.  That is best discussed in topics like "transactions", "ACID", "deadlock".  There is *some* performance hit in such situations, but it is the price to pay for the integrity of the data.  And it does not matter whether the two conflicting "users" are different or the same.